# Trouble looping through XML elements

Tags: xml, loops, xslt, nodes

I'm having trouble looping through nodes. I've got working examples but the XML layout is slightly different.

**XML**

```
<FAMILY>
<FAMILY_NAMES id="1" name="Smith">
   <KID name="Jim">First Born</KID>
   <KID name="Joe">Enjoys playing outside</KID>
   <KID name="Jon">Straight A student</KID>
</FAMILY_NAMES>
<FAMILY_NAMES id="2" name="Barnes">
   <KID name="Mike">Just got his license</KID>
   <KID name="Dan">On vacation</KID>
   <KID name="Ken">Going to graduate school</KID>
</FAMILY_NAMES>
<FAMILY_NAMES id="3" name="Thompsons">
 <KID name="James">Loves sports</KID>
 <KID name="Ben">Middle Child</KID>
 <KID name="Frank">Youngest child</KID>
</FAMILY_NAMES>
</FAMILY
```

I am able to get a list of the families but I need to get a list of the random info between the `KID` tag (such as "Enjoys Playing Outside") under each family. So far, I am only able to get a list of the family names.

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:for-each select="//FAMILY/FAMILY_NAMES">
  <xsl:value-of select="@name"></xsl:value-of><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
   <xsl:for-each select="KID">
     <xsl:value-of select="KID"></xsl:value-of><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Just not sure why this isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you loop through each `KID`, the current node already is each `KID`, so to get the string value of the `KID` use `<xsl:value-of select="."/>`, not `="KID"`.

**This XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="/FAMILY/FAMILY_NAMES">
      <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:for-each select="KID">
        <xsl:text>  </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
        <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Applied to your input XML,**

```
<FAMILY>
  <FAMILY_NAMES id="1" name="Smith">
    <KID name="Jim">First Born</KID>
    <KID name="Joe">Enjoys playing outside</KID>
    <KID name="Jon">Straight A student</KID>
  </FAMILY_NAMES>
  <FAMILY_NAMES id="2" name="Barnes">
    <KID name="Mike">Just got his license</KID>
    <KID name="Dan">On vacation</KID>
    <KID name="Ken">Going to graduate school</KID>
  </FAMILY_NAMES>
  <FAMILY_NAMES id="3" name="Thompsons">
    <KID name="James">Loves sports</KID>
    <KID name="Ben">Middle Child</KID>
    <KID name="Frank">Youngest child</KID>
  </FAMILY_NAMES>
</FAMILY>
```

**Yields the following output:**

```
Smith
  Jim: First Born
  Joe: Enjoys playing outside
  Jon: Straight A student
Barnes
  Mike: Just got his license
  Dan: On vacation
  Ken: Going to graduate school
Thompsons
  James: Loves sports
  Ben: Middle Child
  Frank: Youngest child
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This worked perfectly. And its formatted nicely too. I'll have to look this over and understand each line. Thanks so much.